# Incorrect formatting while reading csv

Tags: python-3.x, csv

CSV format (3 columns):

```
id_numb formatted_id    Comment_Txt
    1    Z007         sample text says good morning.
```

Code to read:

```
with open("file.csv", 'r' ,newline='') as csvfile:
   file_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ',quotechar='|')

   for row in file_reader:  
       print(row)
```

Expected OP:

```
['id_numb', 'formatted_id', 'Comment_Txt']
['1',  'Z007', 'sample','text' ,'says','good','morning.']
```

My OP:

```
['1,Z007,sample',   'text' ,'says','good','morning.']
```

The first 3 tokens are automatically joined. I am not able to understand the mistake. Any suggetsions will be helpful.

Comment: you want `['1',  'Z007', 'sample','text' ,'says','good','morning.']` rather than `['1', 'Z007', 'sample text says good morning.']`? Is it true?

Comment: @pwxcoo you have got the what I want part correctly, what I am getting is different. The first 3 tokens of every row are joined, where it has to be 3 separate tokens. The rest of the op is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import csv
from functools import reduce

with open("file.csv", 'r' ,newline='') as csvfile:
    file_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',',quotechar='|')

    for row in file_reader:
        print(reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [i.split(' ') for i in row]))
```

output:

```
['id_numb', 'formatted_id', 'Comment_Txt']
['1', 'Z007', 'sample', 'text', 'says', 'good', 'morning.']
```

Is it `Expected OP`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using

```
with open("file.csv", 'r' ,newline='') as csvfile:
   file_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',',quotechar='|')

   for row in file_reader:  
       print(row)
```

since your first row seems to be of the form

```
1,Z007,sample text says good morning
```

and using ' ' as a delimiter basically splits anything separated by a space into two different columns.

Comment: I tried that already, since most of the sentences in the third column is long using "," as a delimiter messes up.